# How to stub ink! contract environment to produce fake values for use in tests?

Tags: ink, testing, unit-tests, blocknumber

In an ink! contract I need to use `Self.env().block_number()` to get the current block number to compare it with a `block_number_guessed` value that I provide when instantiating the contract and check that it is less than the current block number.

```rust
impl MyContract {
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(
        block_number_guessed: BlockNumber,
    ) -> Self {
        let mut instance = Self::default();
        let block_number_current = Self::env().block_number();
        assert!(
            block_number_current > block_number_guessed,
            "block number when guessing occurred must be before the current block number"
        );
```

I have written a test but I don't know how to provide a fake value of `Self.env().block_number()` in the unit tests to pretend that the current block number is greater than the fake value of `100` that I have used for `block_number_guessed` so that the assertion in the implementation when the contract is instantiated is satisfied and the test passes.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    use crate::my_contract::MyContract;

    /// We test a simple use case of our contract.
    #[ink::test]
    fn it_works() {
        let block_number_guessed = 100;
        let mut my_contract = MyContract::new(
            block_number_guessed.clone(),
        );
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to use a custom environment `CustomEnvironment` and a custom chain extension `CustomBlocknumberExtension` like mentioned [here](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension#example-environment) as shown in the below code snippet, but I don't know how to write the implementation of `fake_current_block_number`, and I don't know if this is even a valid way to solve the issue.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    use crate::my_contract::MyContract;

    use ink::env::{
        Environment,
        DefaultEnvironment,
    };

    #[ink::chain_extension]
    pub trait CustomBlocknumberExtension {
        type ErrorCode = CustomBlocknumberError;

        #[ink(extension = 0x1111)]
        fn fake_current_block_number() -> BlockNumber>;
    }    

    /// An environment using default ink environment types
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum CustomEnvironment {}

    impl Environment for CustomEnvironment {
        const MAX_EVENT_TOPICS: usize =
            <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::MAX_EVENT_TOPICS;

        type AccountId = <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::AccountId;
        type Balance = <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Balance;
        type Hash = <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Hash;
        type Timestamp = <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Timestamp;
        type BlockNumber = <ink::env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::BlockNumber;

        type ChainExtension = crate::CustomBlocknumberExtension;
    }

    /// We test a simple use case of our contract.
    #[ink::test(env = crate::CustomEnvironment)]
    fn it_allows_use_of_stubbed_blocknumber() {
        assert_eq!(env().extension().fake_current_block_number(), 200);
        ...
    }
}
```

I looked through all the [ink! examples](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples) repository, but I can't find any that stub the ink! environment in their tests.

How should we stub the ink! environment function `Self.env().block_number()`
so we can provide a fake value for the current block number in our unit tests?

Comment: it looks like this feature needs to be added similar to how `set_block_timestamp` was added here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7758/83 in this PR https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1721, but we need to add `set_block_number`. so it could be used like this in tests: `let new_block_number: BlockNumber = 100; ink::env::test::set_block_number::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(new_block_number);`

Comment: i created a PR here to add `set_block_number` here https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1806 and tested that it works in a project here https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/files#diff-ba24f44bc113244a08fc1781375fa5aab36b7587d656c925ee251ff42ac4de3fR362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `advance_block` function in the `ink::env::test` and
you can do something like this:

```rust
fn advance_n_blocks(n: u32) {
    for _ in 0..n {
        advance_block();
    }
}
fn advance_block() {
    ink::env::test::advance_block::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>();
}
```